# Error con $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un *CRUD* pero al insertar me sale el siguiente error:

> "¡Acceso prohibido!
>   Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no puede leerlo.
>   Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
>   Error 403
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 "

Lo que quiero es que cada que inserte me lleve a la misma página pero con el registro insertado el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$sql_local = "SELECT * FROM DATOS_USUARIOS";
$resultado = $base->prepare($sql_local);
$resultado->execute(array());

//--------- insertar datos----------

#si has pulsado el boton insertar
if(isset($_POST["agregar"])) {

    //almaceno las variables del formulario
    $nombre    = $_POST["Nom"];
    $apellido  = $_POST["Ape"];
    $direccion = $_POST["Dir"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO DATOS_USUARIOS (NOMBRE, APELLIDO, DIRECCION) VALUES(:nom, :ape, :dir)";

    $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);

    $resultado->execute(array(
        ":nom" => $nombre,
        ":ape" => $apellido,
        ":dir" => $direccion
    ));

    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>

<h1>CRUD<span class="subtitulo">Create Read Update Delete</span></h1>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="primera_fila">Id</td>
            <td class="primera_fila">Nombre</td>
            <td class="primera_fila">Apellido</td>
            <td class="primera_fila">Dirección</td>
            <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        #por aca objeto persona que hay en el array registros repiteme el codigo que esta en el foreach
        foreach($registros as $persona): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $persona->Id ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $persona->Nombre ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $persona->Apellido ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $persona->Direccion ?></td>

        <?php endforeach; //cierro boloque foreach ?>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='Nom' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='Ape' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
            <td><input type='text' name=' Dir' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
            <td class='bot'><input type='submit' name='agregar' id='agregar' value='Insertar'></td>
        </tr>
<!-- /.. -->
```

Estoy trabajando con phpMyAdmin con MySQL.

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser problema de configuración de directivas del _virtual host_, o de permisos (me suena más a la primera opción). Y otro detalle, en el `action`del formulario la variable creo que debería ser `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` sin `$` en la `key`.

Comment: @OscarR. Gracias, el error era "$".

Comment: Lo añado como respuesta por si alguien viene con problemas similares.

Comment: @OscarR. Si gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta aqui

```
$_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']
```

PHP_SELF no es una variable, es un valor dentro del arreglo SERVER, prueba poniendo esto

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

Answer (score 1):

El error suele ser síntoma de configuración de directivas del *Virtual Host* o de permisos de acceso.

En este caso, a raíz del comentario, ha resultado ser un error en la configuración del `action` en el formulario.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

La variable `$_SERVER['$PHP_SELF']` se debe definir sin el símbolo `$` en la `key`.

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```